# Capturing objects and checking for equality

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have to test a method where an object is constructed and an operation is performed to return a list of object. To test this i have constructed the same object in my test method. Now how do i capture the object and test whether the two objects are equal.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am missing something, but I think it's going to easy if I have equal and hashcode method overriden for that object class. Like `Assert.assertTrue(expectedObject.equals(actualObject));`